# Convert object values into array the Angular way

Tags: angularjs

I have the follow object:

> ```
>  formData : {
>        _id: "550de8956e2d0948080e220f" 
>        category: "Tag1"
>        isFeatured: "Yes" 
>        likeCount: 557 
>        title: "Integrating WordPress with Your Website"
>     }
> ```

I tried JavaScript but it returned a null value:

```
 var arryFormData = Array.prototype.slice.call(formData)
```

How can I convert formData into an array of just its values, not properties?

As in ...

```
 arryFormData = ["550de8956e2d0948080e220f", "Tag1", "Yes", 557, "Integrating WordPress with Your Website"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using underscore.js,

```
_.values(formData)
// will get ["550de8956e2d0948080e220f", "Tag1", "Yes", 557, "Integrating WordPress with Your Website"]
```

See: [here](http://underscorejs.org/#values)

Alternatively:

```
var res = [];
for (var x in formData){
   formData.hasOwnProperty(x) && res.push(formData[x])
}
console.log(res);
```

In any event, the array elements might not be in the order that you want.

Answer (score 5):

or if You like to more functional code:

```
var arr = [];
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key){
    arr.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer one line solution with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and es6 syntax, until [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is not here

```
const values = Object.keys(obj).map(it => obj[it])
```

or in es5

```
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function(it) { 
   return obj[it]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's No magic way, you just have to use a for loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    values.push(obj[key])
}
```

To make it angular, you could use angular.forEach I guess...

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have handled in Angular 5 to convert Object into Array as API gives response in JSON Object so we can convert it into array to use it.

```
    let tmepArr = {};
    Object.keys(res).forEach( key => {
        tmepArr['name'] = [res[key].name];
        tmepArr['id'] = [res[key].id];
    });
    this.marketplaceDropDown = [tmepArr];
```